# Нет ли стилистической ошибки в данном примере?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Имеется ли ошибка в данном примере: "Я не знала, что любовь – это самый коварный принцип, на который пойдя шанс тотчас оказаться жертвой очень велик"?

Comment: Предложение некорректно, но исправить его сложно, так как семантика неясная. Почему любовь названа принципом, да еще коварным? Какое словарное значение слова "принцип" здесь используется? Также выражение "пойти на принцип" обычно имеет негативную окраску (упрямо настаивать на своих убеждениях).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь неправильное употребление деепричастного оборота (*галлицизм*, прощавшийся разве что Тургеневу, долго жившему во Франции). Обычно пугают таким учебным примером: "Подъезжая к станции, у меня слетела шляпа". Глагол, которому подчинено деепричастие (у вас сказуемое подчинённой части "очень велик"), всегда относится к его же производителю действия, поэтому грамматический смысл вышел такой: "*шанс, пошедший на принцип, очень велик*". Изменить можно, например, так (последний глагол относится к "идущему на принцип", который не назван, а не к "шансу"):

> ...пойдя на который, можно с большой вероятностью [хуже: с большими
>   шансами] оказаться жертвой.
>
> ...пойдя на который, можно получить большой шанс оказаться жертвой.

Без деепричастия:

> ...и, если на него пойти, шанс оказаться жертвой будет очень
>   велик.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за ответ! Но хотелось бы уточнить ещё один момент. Нет ли ошибки в таком примере:"... принцип, на который пойти — значит вмиг оказаться жертвой"?

Answer (score 2):

Если уж согласиться с мнением, что любовь — это коварный принцип, то я бы предложила такой вариант:

***Я не знала, что любовь – это тот опасный принцип, при следовании которому шанс тотчас оказаться жертвой очень велик.***

По крайнем мере, в моем варианте *следовать принципу* — это не *идти на принцип*. И редактирование выполнено достаточно близко к исходному тексту.

Между прочим, 8,4 балла по Главреду. "Коварный" сочли штампом, усилители там тоже не любят. Да только как обойтись без усилителей, просто их не должно быть слишком много. "Коварный" тоже можно оставить, ввиду оригинальности всего словосочетания.

А вы проверяете свой текст по Главреду?  (Это такой шутливый лозунг).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Кстати, 8,4 балла — по чистоте и 10 баллов — по читаемости. А вот здесь я с ними не согласна. Наречие ***тотчас*** не совсем на месте, оно мешает плавному прочтению.

Лучше так: ***Я не знала, что любовь – это тот опасный принцип, при следовании которому / шанс  оказаться жертвой // очень велик.***  (Я указываю произносительные фрагменты, разделенные условными паузами).

Поэтому делаем вывод: возможности ресурса в плане "читаемости" **отнюдь не идеальны.** Интонационную характеристику предложения они не оценивают, а какая еще может быть читаемость.